# mismatched input 'FROM' expecting {<EOF>, 'WHERE', 'GROUP', 'ORDER', 'HAVING', 'LIMIT', 'LATERAL', 'WINDOW', 'UNION', 'EXCEPT'}(line 55, pos 12)

Tags: sql, hive

```
WITH qq1 AS (
          SELECT
            MAX(month_end_dt) AS max_month_end_dt
          FROM
            ods.bde_loan_mly
        ),
        qq2 AS (
          SELECT
            UDF_ADD_MONTHS(current_date, -1) AS curr_date
          FROM
            DUAL
        ),
        qq3 AS (
          SELECT
            TO_CHAR(qq2.curr_date, 'MM/yyyy') AS MONTH
          FROM
            DUAL
        ),
        qq4 AS (
          SELECT
            MAX(history_dt) AS max_history_dt
          FROM
            BUWHSE_RAW.cpipassport
          WHERE
            TO_CHAR(HISTORY_DT, 'MM/yyyy') = (qq3.MONTH)
        ),
        qq5 AS (
          SELECT
            MIN(HISTORY_DT) AS min_history_dt
          FROM
            BUWHSE_RAW.CPIPASSPORT
          WHERE
            TO_CHAR(HISTORY_DT, 'MMYYYY') = TO_CHAR(current_date, 'MMYYYY')
        ),
        qq6 AS (
          SELECT
            MAX(MONTH_END_DT) AS max_month_end_dt_2
          FROM
            ODS.BDE_BORROWER_MLY
        ),
        qq7 AS (
          SELECT
            MAX(MONTH_END_DT) AS max_month_end_dt_3
          FROM
            ods.bde_user_defined_mly
        ),
        qq8 AS (
          SELECT
            TRUNC(LAST_DAY(add_months(current_date, -1))) AS last_day
          FROM
            sys.dual
        )
        SELECT
          *
        FROM
          (
            SELECT
              ODS.BDE_LOAN_MLY.LN_NO,
              ODS.BDE_LOAN_MLY.IV_CAT_CD,
              ODS.BDE_LOAN_MLY.IV_ID,
              ODS.BDE_LOAN_MLY.LN_NXT_PMT_DUE_DT,
              ODS.BDE_LOAN_MLY.LN_SUSPENSE_BA,
              ODS.BDE_LOAN_MLY.LN_1ST_PRIN_BA,
              ODS.BDE_LOAN_MLY.LN_ANN_INT_RT,
              ODS.BDE_LOAN_MLY.LN_HI_TY,
              ODS.BDE_LOAN_MLY.LN_LO_TY,
              ODS.BDE_LOAN_MLY.LN_MATURES_DT,
              ODS.BDE_LOAN_MLY.LN_ARM_CD,
              ODS.BDE_LOAN_MLY.LN_INT_DUE_BA,
              ODS.BDE_LOAN_MLY.LN_CRE_QUL_ORIG_CD,
              ODS.BDE_LOAN_MLY.LN_FC_WKST_STAT_CD,
              ODS.BDE_LOAN_MLY.ELOC_CD,
              ODS.BDE_LOAN_MLY.MONTH_END_DT,
              ODS.BDE_LOAN_MLY.LN_BKR_STATUS_CD,
              ODS.BDE_LOAN_MLY.LN_DIST_TYPE1_INT_ONLY_FLAG,
              ODS.BDE_LOAN_MLY.LN_DIST_TYPE1_INT_ONLY_EXP_DT,
              CALL_RPT_MAPPING.APP_ID,
              CALL_RPT_MAPPING.SCHED_ID,
              CALL_RPT_MAPPING.LINE,
              CALL_RPT_MAPPING.COLUMN_VAL,
              CALL_RPT_MAPPING.DESCR,
              CALL_RPT_MAPPING.REM_TERM,
              CALL_RPT_MAPPING.DELQ_DAYS,
              CALL_RPT_MAPPING.FICO_SCORE_BUCKETS,
              CALL_RPT_MAPPING.FORMULA_CD
            FROM
              ODS.BDE_LOAN_MLY,
              SVC_FINANCE_ODS.CALL_RPT_MAPPING,
              qq1
            WHERE
              MONTH_END_DT = qq1.max_month_end_dt
              AND app_id = 'L'
              AND INSTR(CODE_VALUES, IV_ID) <> 0
          ) a
          LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
              BUWHSE_RAW.CPIPASSPORT.history_dt,
              BUWHSE_RAW.CPIPASSPORT.loan_number,
              BUWHSE_RAW.CPIPASSPORT.BILLING_ADDRESS_LINE_1,
              BUWHSE_RAW.CPIPASSPORT.BILLING_ADDRESS_LINE_2,
              BUWHSE_RAW.CPIPASSPORT.BILLING_ADDRESS_LINE_3,
              BUWHSE_RAW.CPIPASSPORT.BILLING_ADDRESS_LINE_4,
              BUWHSE_RAW.CPIPASSPORT.BILLING_CITY_STATE,
              BUWHSE_RAW.CPIPASSPORT.BILLING_ZIP_CODE,
              BUWHSE_RAW.CPIPASSPORT.SEG_EL_CURR_AVAIL_LIMIT_AMOUNT,
              BUWHSE_RAW.CPIPASSPORT.SEG_EL_LIEN_POSITION_NUMBER,
              BUWHSE_RAW.CPIPASSPORT.LOAN_TERM,
              BUWHSE_RAW.CPIPASSPORT.SEG_EL_CREDIT_LINE_AMOUNT
            FROM
              BUWHSE_RAW.CPIPASSPORT,
              qq4
            WHERE
              HISTORY_DT = qq4.max_history_dt
          ) b ON a.LN_NO = b.loan_number
          LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
              BUWHSE_RAW.CPIPASSPORT.loan_number,
              BUWHSE_RAW.CPIPASSPORT.FIRST_UNAMORTIZED_FEES_AMOUNT
            FROM
              BUWHSE_RAW.CPIPASSPORT,
              qq5
            WHERE
              HISTORY_DT = qq5.min_history_dt
          ) c ON a.LN_NO = c.loan_number
          LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
              LN_NO,
              DECODE (BO_RELATION_CD, 'X', 'X', null) AS MTGR_RELATIONSHIP_CODE,
              BO_SHORT_NM AS CUST_SHORT_NM
            FROM
              ODS.BDE_BORROWER_MLY,
              qq6
            WHERE
              MONTH_END_DT = qq6.max_month_end_dt_2
          ) d ON a.LN_NO = d.LN_NO
          LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
              LN_NO,
              USR_01_POS4B_XX AS FRAUD_INDICATOR
            FROM
              ods.bde_user_defined_mly,
              qq7
            WHERE
              USR_01_POS4B_XX = 'Y'
              AND MONTH_END_DT = qq7.max_month_end_dt_3
          ) e ON a.LN_NO = e.LN_NO
          LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
              A.LN_NO,
              B.OG_MTG_AM AS ORIGINAL_MORTGAGE_AMOUNT,
              A.ORIG_LTV_RATIO_FC AS ORIGINAL_LOAN_TO_VALUE_RATIO,
              CASE WHEN GREATEST(NVL(C.PR_VALUE_AM, 0), NVL(B.OG_PROP_VAL_AM, 0)) = 0 THEN D.APPRAISAL 
                ELSE GREATEST(NVL(C.PR_VALUE_AM, 0), NVL(B.OG_PROP_VAL_AM, 0)) 
              END AS APPRAISAL_AMT,
              B.OG_FHLBB_PUR_PR_AM AS FHLBB_PURCHASE_PRICE,
              DECODE_UDF(
                TRIM(A.LN_LO_TY),
                1,
                'FHA RESIDENTIAL',
                2,
                'VA RESIDENTIAL',
                3,
                'CONVENTIONAL RES WITHOUT PMI',
                4,
                'COMMERCIAL',
                5,
                'FHA PROJECT',
                6,
                'CONVENTIONAL RES WITH PMI',
                7,
                'HUD 235/265',
                8,
                'UNASSIGNED',
                9,
                'FARM LOAN'
              ) AS LO_TYPE_DESCRIPTION
            FROM
              ODS.BDE_LOAN_MLY A,
              ODS.BDE_ORIGINAL_LOAN_MLY B,
              ODS.BDE_PROPERTY_MLY C,
              BUREPORTS.LQ_LOAN_TAPE_FIELDS D,
              qq8
            WHERE
              A.MONTH_END_DT = B.MONTH_END_DT
              AND A.LN_NO = B.LN_NO
              AND A.MONTH_END_DT = C.MONTH_END_DT
              AND A.LN_NO = C.LN_NO
              AND TO_CHAR(A.LN_NO) = D.LOAN_NUMBER (+)
              AND A.IV_ID between '100'
              and '189'
              and A.LN_1ST_PRIN_BA > 0
              AND A.MONTH_END_DT = qq8.last_day
          ) f ON a.LN_NO = f.LN_NO
          LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
              A.LN_NO LN_NO,
              A.AR_ALTNG_AM_CLC_FG ARM_NEG_AMORT_IND
            FROM
              ODS.BDE_NEW_ARM_MLY A,
              qq8
            WHERE
              A.MONTH_END_DT = qq8.last_day
          ) g ON a.LN_NO = g.LN_NO
```

Comment: Can anyone check and give me your comments

Answer (score 0):

There is one small syntactical issue. Please place bracket for the below condition and check again. AND (A.IV_ID between '100' and '189').

Comment: Thanks, I was modified this. But still have this issue for second left outer join query "Detected cartesian product for INNER join between logical plans"